# "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables" pecl extensions build fail on macos High Sierra

Tags: macos, clang, conda, macos-high-sierra, pecl

I'm building my web development IDE on Macos High Sierra 10.13.6 and following this [tutorial](https://www.caseymcmullen.com/2019/02/how-to-install-apache-on-macos-1013.html). I'm at the step where I need to install PHP extensions (scpecially xDebug), but here is the error I get whenever I pecl any extension : `checking whether the C compiler works... no`

The whole log :

```
pecl install xdebug
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading xdebug-2.7.0.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.7.0.tgz (230,326 bytes)
.................................................done: 230,326 bytes
69 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
building in /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-fredericsBTF0Y/xdebug-2.7.0
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.15/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-fredericsBTF0Y/xdebug-2.7.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.15/bin/php-config' failed
```

I read everywhere to check command that line tools are installed, indeed they are (I even deleted them and reinstalled them). Now I have Xcode Version 10.1 and  : `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Gcc works outside of pecl :

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

However, here is something strange:  Clang installed directory is in my python Conda manager !!

```
clang --version
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/frederic/miniconda3/bin

which clang
/Users/frederic/miniconda3/bin/clang
```

Although, when I check via Xcode :

```
xcodebuild -find gcc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc

xcodebuild -find clang
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
```

Can miniconda cause trouble with his own clang ? Or is it something else ?
Thanks

Comment: The message also says `See 'config.log' for more details`. Did you look there? Can you post the relevant details from this log?